# Maple Conversion Command

Tags: maple

I am aware Maple has many commands of the form `convert(a,b)`, where $a$ is usually an expression and $b$ can be a lot of different things, such as `parfrac`.

I've been doing some practice questions, and I'm stumped on this one: If I wanted to convert $\dfrac{1}{2x^3+x^2+2x}$ into $\dfrac{1}{2x}+\dfrac{-\frac{1}{4}+I\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}}{x+\frac{1}{4}-I\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}}+\dfrac{-\frac{1}{4}-I\frac{\sqrt{15}}{60}}{x+\frac{1}{4}+I\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}}$, what would $b$ be in `convert(a,b)`? ( I know $a$ is obviously the expression.)

`I` is the imaginary unit in Maple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
[> f := 1/(2*x^3+x^2+2*x):
 convert(f, parfrac, complex):
 evalf(%);

         (-.25+0.65e-1*I)/(x+.25-.97*I)+.50/x+(-.25-0.65e-1*I)/(x+.25+.97*I)
```

Comment: You know your Maple! +1

Answer (score 2):

You asked about an exact symbolic (ie. not floating point) form as the result.

Below are two approaches. The first is to subsequently apply the `identify` command to an answer (containing floats) obtained by using the `complex` option to the `convert` call. Such an approach often will not work on more involved results.

The second approach below involves trying to figure out a factorization and thus the extension field which may be supplied as another optional argument to the `convert` call. This is followed by a minor rearrangement in order to get `1` as the coefficient of the leading terms of the polynomials in the denominators, similar to how you cast it.

```
restart:

a:=1/(2*x^3+x^2+2*x):

# One way...

sort(identify(convert(a,parfrac,complex)));

          1    1    (1/2)  (1/2)      1    1    (1/2)  (1/2) 
        - - - -- I 3      5         - - + -- I 3      5      
   1      4   60                      4   60                 
  --- + ------------------------- + -------------------------
  2 x       1   1    (1/2)  (1/2)       1   1    (1/2)  (1/2)
        x + - + - I 3      5        x + - - - I 3      5     
            4   4                       4   4                

# Another (somewhat successful) way...

A:=denom(a);

                          /   2        \
                        x \2 x  + x + 2/

Q:=map(radnormal,
       convert(a, parfrac,
               {I} union indets([solve(A/x^(ldegree(A)))],radical)
               )
       );

                  (1/2)                            (1/2)     
        -15 + I 15              1         15 + I 15          
   ------------------------- + --- - ------------------------
      /     (1/2)          \   2 x      /    (1/2)          \
   15 \-I 15      + 4 x + 1/         15 \I 15      + 4 x + 1/

sort(add(subs(R=(numer(1/t)/lcoeff(numer(1/t))),
              S=denom(1/t)/lcoeff(numer(1/t)),
              S/R),
         t in Q));

                1    1     (1/2)      1    1     (1/2) 
              - - + -- I 15         - - - -- I 15      
         1      4   60                4   60           
        --- + ------------------- + -------------------
        2 x       1     (1/2)   1       1     (1/2)   1
              x - - I 15      + -   x + - I 15      + -
                  4             4       4             4
```